# Idlex 1.13 : Unable to located "idlexlib"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-idle

I really like IDLE because it's simple and intuitive, not to mention it is lightweight, but one turnoff is its lack of Line Numbers which is very important (for me).

I installed Python 3.6.0 for all users and then installed IdleX (python setup.py install), both as Admin. The setup went smoothly and the console displayed all processes just fine. However,  when I tried to run idlex, an error showed:

**Unable to located "idlexlib".**

**Make sure it is located in the same directory as "idlexlib" or run setup.py**

**to install IdleX.**

```
 python setup.py install --user
```

I tried uninstalling IDLE then installed it for single user, reboot then run again but the problem is still the same.
I tried upgrading to Python 3.6.1 but with no luck. I also tried copying **LineNumbers.py** to **idlelib** then edited **configextensions.def** but still no luck.

This should be a textbook setup (or so I thought) but I can't get it to work.

P.S.: Using Windows 10, 64-bit

Comment: It is possible that idlex is not compatible with IDLE on 3.6.  I don't know either way.

Comment: I found out that IDLEX 1.13 does not work on Python 3.6.0 and v 3.6.1. The latest version it is compatible with is Python 3.5.3 32-bit. Thanks @TerryJanReedy. I thought something was wrong with how I set the PATH. Incompatibility was the last thing on my mind.

Answer (score 1):

### Prerequisites

This solution works on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS,
using

- python3
- idle3
- python3-setuptools
- idlex-1.18.zip

The solution to the *issue* comes in the form of installing **idlex**, but there's more to it than that, so I've written the whole process.

### Update Repo & Install dependencies

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y idle3 python3-setuptools
```

### Download IDLEx extension package

```
sudo wget http://sourceforge.net/projects/idlex/files/idlex-1.18.zip -P ~/
```

### Unzip & make idlex hidden

```
cd ~/
unzip idlex-1.18
mv idlex-1.18 .idlex-1.18
```

### Remove extra directories

```
rm -rf ~/idlex-1.18 ~/idlex-1.18.zip
```

### Install idlex

```
cd ~/.idlex-1.18
sudo python3 setup.py install
```

### Ensure Idlex runs

```
cd ~/.idlex-1.18
python3 idlex.py
```

Exit the program and proceed to next step.

## Create Desktop Shortcut

### Setup desktop shortcut for easy access

```
nano ~/Desktop/idlex.desktop
```

Paste into the text file:

```
python3 ~/.idlex-1.18/idlex.py
```

Press Ctrl+X and type "Y" and enter to save file to desktop.

### Make idlex.desktop executable

#### In terminal, or

```
sudo chmod +x ~/Desktop/idlex.desktop
```

#### Through gnome

Right-click idlex.desktop on your desktop > select "Properties":

- Go to **Permissions** tab
- Check the box, "Allow executing file as program"