# Running Idlex 1.13 on Python 3.6.1

Tags: python, python-idle, setup.py

I wanted to get horizontal scrolling for the Python IDLE, and that led me to downloading idlex 1.13. Unzipping it went fine, but I wasn't able to run idlex.py

Every time I try, I get a message like this:

```
Unable to located "idlexlib".
Make sure it is located in the same directory as "idlexlib" or run setup.py
to install IdleX.
```

---

```
python setup.py install --user
```

I'm not sure if 1.13 just doesn't work on Python 3.6.1, or if I'm missing something like folder placement or if I should be running a different file.

I am using Windows 10 on a 64-bit operating system.

Comment: Have you tried running `setup.py`? If yes, what didn't work for you? Did you get any error? If no, why not do it now?

Comment: I am hoping to add a horizontal scrollbar by 3.6.3.  I know, won't help you now.  Are you aware that you can increase the default editor width on the General tab of the Preferences dialog?  Most screens should allow at least 120 chars.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that Idlex is not compatible with Python 3.6.0 and Python 3.6.1. It is, however, compatible with Python 3.5.3 32-bit and before. I had the same issue, until I found another post on StackOverflow:
[Idlex 1.13 : Unable to located "idlexlib"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43012037/idlex-1-13-unable-to-located-idlexlib)

Comment: How to install it for version 3.5.3 when 2.7.1 is already installed

Comment: Idlex should work with Python 2.7.1, but if you want to make the switch to Python 3 (Which is a different language. To find out more about the difference go to: https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3) you can go to https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-353/ and dowload the file for your operating system.